# Automate after commit tasks when developing custom web apps with php

Tags: php, svn, automation, hosting

I'm having a problem using SVN:

I usually do more than 2 commits per day to a [private svn hosting company]. The applications we code are php based, use mySQL databases, jQuery, etc.

I'd like to know if there's something available that allows me to automate these kind of tasks:

- clean web application files from svn (remove .svn folders and hidden files)
- ftp the changes made to client's working copy of the application
- update changes (if made) to mySQL database in some way
- etc.

**I mean:**

We want to get a tool (or svn hosting service) that allows us to automate those kind of tasks after each commit so client can see the changes made instantly in his domain, etc., without doing all those tedious common tasks that make devs loose valuable time.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Enrique

Comment: [Beanstalkapp.com](http://beanstalkapp.com/) does offer custom web hooks (http postback on every commit), automated S/FTP deployments, etc. You should check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Is cleaning up svn files not as simple as making an alias/script to delete any files with .svn in them? Or starting with the period.

Is svn updating on the clients working copy very time consuming? I guess it depends on the amount of data you're dealing with, but it should usually be a quick process.

As for database updating, to my knowledge there's no way to merge content or anything, however tools like dbdeploy could help with version controlling the schema. You could of course make a script that does a mysql dump of the database you want and imports it into the current database, replacing any site-specific values (site urls) as you went.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend Webistrano, check it out at https://github.com/peritor/webistrano/wiki/

You can add in plenty of custom actions.  I currently use it to deploy SVN/GIT commits on Drupal sites.  This enables me to forget about the tedious things like changing my settings from localhost to the production site(s).

Enjoy!
-Curtis

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure about downloading this tool, setting up Ruby on Rails, etc. for doing all this stuff. Do you think it worths the effort?